# Difference between these two while loop conditions in my string copy function

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to make my own string copy function and I'm having trouble understanding the difference between these two code snippets from my two versions of my function which I though were equivalent.

Example 1

```
while (*str1 = *str2)
{
    str1++;
    str2++;
}
```

Example 2

```
while (*str1)
{
    str1 = str2;
    str1++;
    str2++;
}
```

Where `str1` and `str2` are the two string im passing to my function.

The first example works as I expect but the second one limits my string to the length of the first.

so if

`str1` is `ABCDEF`

`str2` is `abcdefghijkl`

After the second version of my string copy runs

`str1` is now `abcdef`

The first works properly as expected

`str1` is now `abcdefghijkl`

I'm assuming my while condition is the culprit. What is the difference between the two conditions `(*str1)` and `(*str1 = *str2)`? I'm still learning C/C++ so sorry if it's a noob question.

Comment: Well the first one does what you want. The second one not so much.

Comment: 1. C and C++ are separate languages. They share some things, but they should never be considered the same. 2. How exactly did you allocate  `str1` that it would work with a longer string? if you were writing past the allocated memory it would be UB

Comment: Sure you did not want `*str1 = *str2;` instead of `str1 = str2;` in the 2nd code?

Comment: Also, in your first example, your compiler should be suggesting an additional set of parenthesis around your assignment in the `while` loop test clause (e.g. `while ((*str1 = *str2))` )

Comment: This is why it is better program this kind of thing with index variables rather than using games with pointers.

Comment: You are right @chux fixed now

Comment: Changing the post after answers that address the problem is bad form on Stack-overflow.  Rolling back edit.  It you have a new question, post the new question as a new post.

Answer (score 5):

There is a huge difference between `str1 = str2` and `*str1 = *str2`. The first one assigns address in pointer `str2` into the pointer `str1`. Second one assigns element pointed by `str2` to the space pointed by `str1`.

And `while` conditions are little bit different too:
`while (*str1 = *str2)` effectively checks result of this assigment - so `*str2`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to put str1 = str2. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

In the second version, the str1++ increments the pointer to spin through the string.

> while (*str1)

is asking, after each increment, if the value at the current position is null. If it is, the while loop quits (so it will only go through as many times as str1 is long).

The first version is exceptionally poor code (IMO). I would never do an assignment and a test inside the while expression. 90% of people reading this code would not see that because no-one does puts an assignment inside of a while or if test.

Edit: changed percentage.

Comment: With 27 viewers I'm one and yourself, so 7+%, of those who saw right away an assignment was done in the loop.

Comment: I saw it--I would just never do it. 93% would miss it on first view.

Comment: Use the right tool in the C toolbox for the right job.  Sometimes an assignment in a `while` is idiomatic like `int ch; while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) { do_stuff(ch); }`.  Sure it can be done different ways.  IAC, follow your group's coding standards.  BTW: @KIIV saw it too , so at _least_ 10% saw it.

Answer (score 1):

the first assigns the values of str2 to str1 so if the value of str2 is null then the conditions fails.

the bad thing above if str2 is larger than str1 which will write to outbound of str1 thus a segfault.

the second scans the value of str1 so as long as it's not null terminator it returns true thus it continue until a null terminator is reached then it breaks.

caution:

in the second inside loop you make pointer str1 points to where pointer str2 to points! so if they are dynamically allocated then hello a "Memory Leak".

```
char* str1 = new char[10];
char* str2 = new char[20];

while(*str1)
{
     str1 = str2; // Memory leak you should cleaned str1 before here!
     //....
}
```

Comment: The first one is an assignment, not a comparison.

Comment: @PeteBecker sorry I didn't notice that.